# What is the best way to show contact details selected from phonebook

Tags: android

Being the new one to android, I am asking this for your expert opinion,

I am selecting Contact from Phone book and want to show its Phone no(user should choose one if many) & email address.

User can add three users.

Want to store this. (Advise best way. Prefferences, DB or File Sharing)

Urgent reply is requested

Comment: for adding 3 users sharepreference is a suited option

Comment: Usually `Preferences` is used to store small amount of data such User Name, Password which you can use throughout your application.If you have large amount of data then you should use `SQlite` Database.

Answer (score 0):

For ur need Shared prefs is best becoz:

```
   -U are storing only one of the availabe data(which says the data is without any external relation)

   -Retrieval is easier in shared prefs than DB :)
```

So u can use it for ur scenario